# What's the first version of Hibernate that support Oracle19C after the v3.5.4?

Tags: hibernate, java-8, oracle19c, tomcat8.5

I use the hibernate version 3.5.4 on my web app and now the database is changed to Oracle19c.

After this migration I see that the module with Hibernate, when invoking any package with stored procedure that also uses temporary tables, going in ReadTimeOut.

I think that the hibernate version is too old for Oracle19C so I would want know what's the first version of Hibernate that support Oracle19C after the v3.5.4. Is there any site/blog where can I find this info?

Test and evidence:

I have tried also to recompile the package with logs but seems that when the software going in timeout, the package has not been never called.

What is unusual is that the behavior is random; when I recompile the package and restart the Tomcat, the package has been called and work just the first time.

I don't know if the two things are connected but that's what I saw

Comment: Not sure the cause without details, can you provide how are you calling the package and your hibernate configuration?

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, the issue was solved by excluding the temporary tables. In fact, after having been replaced intoprocedure, the issue disappeared.